# Boostrap form input arrange in column

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-modal

I need to display a modal which will allow user to input name and some details. I just want display 2 input filed per row.

Below is the code which display input field in 4 rows, I need to display in 2 rows only.How it's possible.

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Fill the details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="container">
                   <!--<h2> Horizontal form: control states</h2>-->
                  <form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input class="form-control"  type="text" readonly>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address1</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address2</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input class="form-control"  type="text">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                   </form>
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    <!-- ^^^^^^Modal content^^^^^^^-->

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btnmodal btn-default" onclick="okButtonClick()">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--^^^^^^^^ Modal ^^^^^^^^-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `form-group` as a row by adding the class `.row` into the `form-group`, and merge the each of two `col-sm-3` under one `form-group` like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input class="form-control"  type="text" readonly>
      </div>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input class="form-control" type="text">
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
       <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address1</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
       </div>
       <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address2</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap two of the form controls inside a

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        Form control 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        Form control 2
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        Form control 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        Form control 4
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

This should separate the form controls so only 2 show on one line. The clear fix is there for a css style which usually is set as

```
.clearfix {
    clear:both
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy pest code in individual file and check in your local it will run. perfect.
Given below is modern way of doing it. You can refer [this link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) for further details of the way of creating modal dynamically.

```js
function showForm() {
  var msg = $('#form-container');
  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Default Title',
    message: $('#form-container'),
    buttons: [{
      label: 'Submit',
      action: function(dialog) {
        // What to do on submit goes here.
      }
    }, {
      label: 'Close',
      action: function(dialog) {
        dialog.close();
      }
    }],
    onhide: function(dialog) {
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  //width : 800px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="showForm()">Show Form</button>

<div style="display : none" id="hidden-div">

  <div class="container-fluid" id="form-container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly>
        </div>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```